# Make NSConnection stall until connection for registered name is found

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults, distributed-objects, nsconnection

Is there any way to have NSConnection search for a connection with a registered name on, say a separate thread, or scheduled in the run loop, with a callback when a connection is made?  Currently I am using

`[NSConnection connectionWithRegisteredName:kRemotePreferencesDOName host:nil]`

but this simply returns (nil I think) if the connection is not found, rather than stall or otherwise give a callback.  While this makes sense for a server-client relationship, the 'server' and 'client' are both just applications, which may or may not be open at any time, regardless of the other, so it is very likely that the client will be open and doing something when the server launches (and registers its name).  At this point ideally the client will be notified/a connection will be created to the server.

If it helps, this is part of a way for a System Preferences preference pane to control the NSUserDefaults of a target (background-only) application, which may or may not be running when the user opens the preference pane.

Answer (score 1):

Just use while loop to wait for remote object to be ready. Use Thread if application want to perform some other operation while waiting for connection.

```
NSDistantObject *pObj = nil;

while(nil == pObj)
{
    pObj = [[NSConnection rootProxyForConnectionWithRegisteredName:kRemotePreferencesDOName
                                                              host:nil] retain];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.]];
}
```